# How do I identify a value that belongs to a specific category in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to have a result in a cell. dividing into groups of categories.
I have a problem with the B10 cell, I can't solve it.

[image]

> The incomplete working formula is this

`=ArrayFormula(SE(C10<>"",SE(G$2 = E10,G$1,D$1),""))`

Thank you.

Comment: What is your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Aerials now it's better? I also posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it with this.

=ArrayFormula(IFS(C10<>"",SE(O(E10=G$2,E10=H$2),G$1,D$1)))